# Jackson: Overriding JsonSerializable.serialize()

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

I have an abstract class with a lot of subclasses. I want to add custom serialization functionality to the parent and most of the subs by implementing Jackson's JsonSerializable interface. What would be the best way to extend the serialization of the parent in the subs? To write a proper Json-object I need to place my serialization code between calls to JsonGenerator.writeStartObject() + writeEndObject(). So just overriding JsonSerializable.serialize like this won't do:

```
 class Parent implements JsonSerializable {

        String parentField;

        @Override
        public void serialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

            gen.writeStartObject();
            gen.writeStringField("parentField", parentField);
            gen.writeEndObject(); // Closing Object..
        }

        @Override
        public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {}

 }

    class Sub extends Parent {

        String subField;

        @Override
        public void serialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

            super.serialize(gen, serializers); 
            //-> Json-object already closed, subField ends up outside..
            gen.writeStringField("subField", subField); 

        }


    }
```

Comment: what issue do you have?

Comment: Have a look at the code snippet. After calling super.serialize() in the sub, the Json-object has already been closed by gen.writeEndObject(), so every field the overriden method generates doesn't end up in the same object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use classic inheritence and polymorphism by delegating the work to other methods:

```
    public class Parent implements JsonSerializable {

        String parentField;

        @Override
        public void serialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {

            startSerialize(gen);
            doSerialize(gen, serializers);
            endSerialize(gen);
        }

        @Override
        public void serializeWithType(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers, TypeSerializer typeSer) throws IOException {
        }

        protected void startSerialize(JsonGenerator gen) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStartObject();
        }

        protected void doSerialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStringField("parentField", parentField);
        }

        protected void endSerialize(JsonGenerator gen) throws IOException {
            gen.writeEndObject(); // Closing Object..
        }
    }

    public class Sub extends Parent {

        String subField;

        @Override
        protected void doSerialize(JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
            gen.writeStringField("subField", subField);
        }
    }
}
```